# android 2.x Dialog with windowAnimationStyle cannot be dismissed

Tags: android

I find that on android 2.3.3(emulator) and 2.3.4(huawei phone), a Dialog with windowAnimationStyle cannot be dismissed. Here is my code in Activity:

```
private Dialog mDialog;
private View mDialogView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mDialog.dismiss();

        super.handleMessage(msg);

    }

};

public void clickButton2(View view) {

    mDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Toalog);
    mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toast_view, null);
    mDialog.setContentView(mDialogView);
    mDialog.setTitle("title");
    mDialog.show();
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000);
}
```

and code in style.xml

```
<style name="Toalog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ShalogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="ShalogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

code in /anim/fade_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="@integer/enterfadeduration" />
```

/anim/fade_out.xml is similar to fade_in.xml

run this code, then you can see the dialog always display on the screen, and the app won't respond to your click. If you try reinstall it by eclipse, the emulator crash.

everything works fine on android 4.4.4(Xiaomi phone) and 4.2.2(xolo phone)

is it a bug? Or it's my mistake?

The only solution I figure out is not to use windowAnimationStyle on 2.x or lower. I don't know what will happen on android 3.x

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Why are you coding for Android 2.x? Gingerbread is less than 12% now. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Also, supporting version 3.x is pointless; it has less than 0.1% of devices

Comment: @Bowersbros In China, we have to make our app run through android 2.2 to the latest edition